# What are the sizes used for the iOS application splash screen?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, splash-screen, ipod-touch

I am developing an application using the iOS SDK. I need to know what `Default` splash screen sizes I need.

Comment: Just an aside: remember iOS discourages using Splash Screens. Instead use a Launch Image. They are technically the same, but conceptually different. An Splash Screen is usually used as a branding image, while a Launch Screen is a prerendered image of your UI that gives the user the impression the app is loading faster. Check [iOS Human Interface Gudelines in this concern](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/LaunchImages.html)

Answer (score 181):

## 2018 Update - Please don't use this info !

*I'm leaving the below post for reference purposes.*

Please read Apple's documentation [Human Interface Guidelines - Launch Screens](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/launch-screen/) for details on launch screens and recommendations.

Thanks
Drekka

---

**July 2012 - As this reply is rather old, but stills seems popular. I've written a blog post based on Apple's doco and [placed it on my blog](http://drekka.github.com/2012/07/30/iOS-icons-and-splash-screens.html). I hope you guys find it useful.**

Yes. In iPhone/iPad development the `Default.png` file is displayed by the device automatically so you don't have to program it which is really useful. I don't have it with me, but you need different PNGs for the iPad with specific names. I googled `iPad default png` and got [this info](http://phunkwerk.posterous.com/ipad-managing-multiple-launch-images-aka-defa) from the **phunkwerks** site:

---

### iPad Launch Image Orientations

To deal with various orientation options, a new naming convention has been created for iPad launch images. The screen size of the iPad is 768×1024, notice in the dimensions that follow the height takes into account a 20 pixel status bar.

#### Filename Dimensions

- `Default-Portrait.png` * — 768w x 1024h
- `Default-PortraitUpsideDown.png` — 768w x 1024h
- `Default-Landscape.png` ** — 1024w x 748h
- `Default-LandscapeLeft.png` — 1024w x 748h
- `Default-LandscapeRight.png` — 1024w x 748h
- `iPad-Retina–Portrait.png` — 1536w x 2048h
- `iPad-Retina–Landscape.png` — 2048w x 1496h
- `Default.png` — Not recommended

*—If you have not specified a `Default-PortraitUpsideDown.png` file, this file will take precedence.

**—If you have not specified a `Default-LandscapeLeft.png` or `Default-LandscapeRight.png` image file, this file will take precedence.

[This link to "Apple's Developer Library"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW12) is useful, too.

Comment: Note that the Default.png is what's used for the iPhone when running the universal application on that device, so it needs to be your standard 320 x 480 or 320 x 460 image.  The "not recommended" is only for iPad-only applications.

Comment: Thanks! I'm now using a Default-Portrait.png with 768w x 1024h this size seems to work too.

Comment: My app will by default works in Landscape mode. But how can I specify landscape default image for iPhone?

Comment: It's worth to note that if you're using localized versions, you need to remove these files from your root folder and put them into your <language>.lproj directory.

Comment: very useful! thanks however link to apple developer web should also be part of answer - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW12

Comment: The link to the blog in the post does not work anymore. The link above to Apple developer web does not work anymore either.

Comment: Hi guys, I'm the author of the original blog which is long gone and way to old anyway. The Apple documentation now at https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/launch-screen/ gives you the sizes of the screens. Please consider using simple launch storyboards as per Apples recommendations wherever possible as it's far easier that crafting all the pngs.

Answer (score 31):

As of July 2013 (iOS 6), this is what we always use:

```
IPHONE SPLASH 
Default.png - 320 x 480
Default@2x.png - 640 x 960 
Default-568h@2x.png - 640 x 1096 (with status bar)
Default-568h@2x.png - 640 x 1136 (without status bar)

IPAD SPLASH 
iPadImage-Appname-Portrait.png * 768w x 1004h (with status bar)
iPadImage-Appname-Portrait@2x.png * 1536w x 2008h (with status bar)
iPadImage-Appname-Landscape.png ** 1024w x 748h (with status bar)
iPadImage-Appname-Landscape@2x.png ** 2048w x 1496h (with status bar)

iPadImage-Appname-Portrait.png * 768w x 1024h (without status bar)
iPadImage-Appname-Portrait@2x.png * 1536w x 2048h (without status bar)
iPadImage-Appname-Landscape.png ** 1024w x 768h (without status bar)
iPadImage-Appname-Landscape@2x.png ** 2048w x 1536h (without status bar)

ICON
Appname-29.png
Appname-29@2x.png
Appname-50.png
Appname-50@2x.png
Appname-57.png
Appname-57@2x.png
Appname-72.png
Appname-72@2x.png
iTunesArtwork (512px x 512px)
iTunesArtwork@2x (1024px x 1024px)
```

Comment: Shouldn't Default-568h@2x.png be 640 x 1136?

Answer (score 16):

For iOS7 create launch images in the following sizes:

For iPhone 5 and iPod touch (5th generation):

- 640 x 1136 pixels

For other iPhone and iPod touch devices:

- 640 x 960 pixels
- 320 x 480 pixels (standard resolution)

For iPad portrait:

- 1536 x 2048 pixels
- 768 x 1024 pixels (standard resolution)

For iPad landscape:

- 2048 x 1536 pixels
- 1024 x 768 pixels (standard resolution)

See [iOS 7 Design Resources > iOS Human Interface Guidelines > Launch Images](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/LaunchImages.html)

**UPDATE 1**

For iPhone 6:

- 750 x 1334 (@2x) for portrait
- 1334 x 750 (@2x) for landscape

For iPhone 6 Plus:

- 1242 x 2208 (@3x) for portrait
- 2208 x 1242 (@3x) for landscape

**UPDATE 2**

For iPhone X:

- 1125 x 2436 (@3x) for portrait
- 2436 x 1125 (@3x) for landscape

Comment: Bro, Could you please checkout my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43955856/different-launch-screen-image-or-background-image-sizes-for-ios-devices ?

Comment: i wish there was a nice table here with file name and image resolution for each entry, oh and forget iOS 5,6,7. we're in 2017.

Answer (score 10):

## Update 2020 - Xcode 11

In `Xcode 11`, you can provide only one image with 1x, 2x, and 3x scales then set it in `LaunchScreen.storyboard` to fill up the screen and everything goes well!

> For Example: (1242pt x 2688pt @1x)

This is the portrait screen size of `iPhone 11 Pro Max` which is the large iPhone screen size yet so it will give you high-quality splash screen on all iOS devices.

## Update 2019 - iOS 12

I have collected all sizes needed for the splash screen. All u need is to just drag images with these sizes and drop them, Xcode will place each size in the right place.

Good luck.

## Sizes :

320×480

640×960

640×1136

750×1334

768×1004

768×1024

828×1792

1024×748

1024×768

1125×2436

1242×2208

1242×2688

1536×2008

1536×2048

1792×828

2048×1496

2048×1536

2208×1242

2436×1125

2688×1242

> ## Note
>
> Count of required images are 26 images
> but there are 6 duplicated sizes
> so u will find the above sizes are only 20.

Comment: So I need 20 different images just for the splash screen? Seriously?

Comment: Yes. It is not that hard! Your designer should do it easily.

Comment: You can use any online splash screen generator.. so by providing a single image.. it will generate all the required splash of all sizes

Comment: What should be the DPI with this sizes while designing in Photoshop 72 or 300 or any other?

Comment: @kumar which generator can you recommend? Ape tools screws up gradient backgrounds all the time.

Answer (score 8):

You can make them 1024 x 768. You can also check "Status bar is initially hidden" in the plist file.

Answer (score 3):

Here I can add Resolutions and Display Specifications for iphone 6 & 6+ size:

iPhone 6+ - Asset Resolution (@3x) - Resolution (2208 x 1242)px

iPhone 6  - Asset Resolution (@2x) - Resolution (1334 x 750)px

iPad Air / Retina iPad (1st & 2nd Generation / 3rd & 4th) - Asset Resolution (@2x) - Resolution (2048 x 1536)px

iPad Mini (2nd & 3rd Generation) - Asset Resolution (@2x) - Resolution (2048 x 1536)px

iPhone (6, 5S, 5, 5C, 4S, 4) - App Icon (120x120 px) - AppStore Icon (1024x1024 px) - Spotlight (80x80 px) - Settings (58x58 px)

iPhone (6+) - App Icon (180x180 px) - AppStore Icon (1024x1024 px) - Spotlight (120x120 px) - Settings (87x87 px)

Comment: iPhone 6+ the resolution is 1242x 2208. [(https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH22-SW1)]

Comment: For iPhone 6:
750 x 1334 (@2x) for portrait
1334 x 750 (@2x) for landscape

For iPhone 6 Plus:
1242 x 2208 (@3x) for portrait
2208 x 1242 (@3x) for landscape

Comment: @imti, Could you please check out my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43955856/different-launch-screen-image-or-background-image-sizes-for-ios-devices   bro?

Comment: @MayPhyu Sorry Bro, I was out of touch for sudden reason. I hope your problem has been sorted out. If It still uncleared, let me know.

Comment: bro @imti, it's ok bro. It was fixed. But, I have any problem. Could you please help me check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44304498/how-to-set-font-family-to-navigation-controller-title-in-swift   ?

Answer (score 3):

**For Xcode 9 and latest devices**

**Portrait**

iPhone 4/4S **640 x 960**

iPhone 5/5C/5S iPod touch 5th generation **640 x 1136**

iPhone 6/7/8 7**50 x 1334**

iPhone 6/7/8 Plus **1242 x 2208**

iPhone X **1125 x 2436**

iPad non-retina **768 x 1024**

iPad retina **1536 x 2048**

**Landscape**

iPhone 6, 7 and 8 plus **2208 x 1242**

iPhone X **2436 x 1125**

iPad non-retina **1024 x 768**

iPad retina **2048 x 1536**

Answer (score 2):

With iOS 7+, static Launch Images are now deprecated.

You should create a custom view that composes slices of images, which sizes to all screens like a normal UIViewController view.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html

Answer (score 1):

With universal app I had iPad splash screen showing up in simulator but not on device.  The iPad would instead show the Default.png splash for the iPhone.  The Default-Landscape.png and Default-Portrait.png files existing, so wth?  Resolution should be correct since I created the screen captures using Window | Organizer | Screenshots and used 'Save as Default Image' for the iPad, then just renamed it.

Turns out (from my one app anyways) the two iPad screen shots have to be moved to the Resources-iPad directory. Then it all works fine. Seems obvious now, but in case anyone else has lost sleep over this...
-Larry

Answer (score 1):

For Adobe AIR iOS Developers, take note that if your iPad Splash images "shift" or display and scale a second later, it's because there are different dimensions depending on what version of AIR you're using.

Default-Portrait.png:
768 x 1004 (AIR 3.3 and earlier)
**768 x 1024 (AIR 3.4 and higher)**

Default-Portrait@2x.png:
1536 x 2008 (AIR 3.3 and earlier)
**1536 x 2048 (AIR 3.4 and higher)**

Reference:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS901d38e593cd1bac1e63e3d129907d2886-8000.html#WS901d38e593cd1bac58d08f9112e26606ea8-8000