# How to set default.png picture in landscape mode in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

my app's orientation is in landscape right. and i want to set default.png image which is loaded for few seconds at the start of my app. right now i have added default.png in my app. but its showing me image in portrait mode. what should i do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Default-Portrait.png` and `Default-Landscape.png` as image names in iPad.

`Default.png` only works with one image for both orientations in iPhone

And add below in **info.plist** file ,if you do'nt have

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
```

Look at the article  [Default.png and landscape mode](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/user-interface/defaultpng-and-landscape-mode.html)

Comment: info.plist ? looks something different !! can you please give me some step ?

Comment: @Devang: Open "info.plist" in "Dashcode", Go to "info.plist" in your project folder structure, Right click on "info.plist" file then click on "Open With" and choose "DashCode" then cop/paste the above content ..

Comment: @Steven Kramer : Do you want it for iPad ?

Comment: No, just curious! Last I heard, the `Default-Landscape.png` etcetera was not supported on iPhone.

Comment: @Steven Kramer:for iPad ... will have to use UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad instead of UISupportedInterfaceOrientations.

Comment: Okay, so you are saying that "Default-Landscape.png" is supported on iPhone? Thanks!

Comment: @Steven Kramer : No dude "Default-Landscape.png"  supported in iPad only not iPhone .. See SO post                                        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634898/splash-screen-for-universal-application-for-ipad-and-iphone