# iPhone/iPad :How do i set different splash screen in my universal app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

I am having universal app. And i want to to display splash screen with different resolutions for iphone and ipad. 
How can i set it ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [splash screen for Universal application for ipad and iphone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634898/splash-screen-for-universal-application-for-ipad-and-iphone)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [reference documents](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BuildTimeConfiguration/BuildTimeConfiguration.html)

> To demonstrate the naming conventions,
>   suppose your iOS application’s
>   Info.plist file included the
>   UILaunchImageFile key with the value
>   MyLaunchImage. The standard resolution
>   version of the launch image would be
>   named MyLaunchImage.png and would be
>   in a portrait orientation (320 x 480).
>   The high-resolution version of the
>   same launch image would be named
>   MyLaunchImage@2x.png. If you did not
>   specify a custom launch image name,
>   these files would need to be named
>   Default.png and Default@2x.png,
>   respectively.

Comment: @ 7KV7: Thanks for your simple and effective help.

Comment: Beware: you want to be able to address at least three different resolutions: iPhone/iPod, iPad, iPhone retina. You cannot accomplish this just appending a `@2x` to the file name. You will have to change the properties in the Info.plist file

Answer (score 0):

The default image for the portrait orientation has to be named “Default-Portrait.png” and needs the dimensions 768×1024.

Answer (score 0):

You can append the device modifier at the end of the file name. I.E. the iPad splash screens will end with `~ipad.png`

Or, you can change the Info.plist setting using these keys:

```
<key>UILaunchImageFile</key>
<string>Default</string>
<key>UILaunchImageFile~ipad</key>
<string>Default_iPad</string>
```