# Convert iPhone app to universal binary (part II)

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have adjusted my target to be universal. Now the images look scaled up. Do I have to have every image twice, in different resolutions?

What's the correct way to do this? Or do I make images in iPad resolution and use them on the Phone as well?

And: if I do have to duplicate every image, is there a convention such as having the img.png for the iPhone in the `Resources` folder and the img.png for the Pad in the `Resources-iPad` folder?

Many thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best, and well the correct way to do this is to have 3 of every image
320x480 Default.png for iPhone
640x960 Default@2x.png for iPhone 4
and for iPad 768x1024 [iPad Default Image sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634898/splash-screen-for-universal-application-for-ipad-and-iphone)

But if your trying to keep your app as small in size as possible then making the images in retina resolution would be the best way to achieve this. The difference on iPad if scaled correctly wouldn't be noticed. Just be sure not to title the retina images with the "@2x" suffix and scale to fill on low resolution for low resolution iPone interfaces.

Comment: And the same for *all* background images, button icons, menu icons, etc.? So I triple the number of images in my project? I assume yes and "Default.png" was used as an example by you.

Comment: Yes that is correct, and I did use Default as an example. Good luck with your project

Answer (score 2):

No I just suggest having them in one resolution (iPad) and they will scale down.

Actually I suggest making all graphics Retina compatible and then they will look fine on the iPad.

Comment: thank you for your answer! Is Retina resolution different from iPad? I thought they were the same. Need to go and check that on the internet.