# Default.png for ipad and iphone

Tags: iphone, ipad, splash-screen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [splash screen for Universal application for ipad and iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634898/splash-screen-for-universal-application-for-ipad-and-iphone)

How to keep Default.png with two sizes one for ipad and another for iphone?

Comment: @7KV That's wrong, @2x is used for retina display.

Comment: @Eiko: Sorry man.. You are right, didnt read the question properly...Careless.. :P Thanks...

Comment: i tried it that way and kept two images in folders named iphone and ipad in resources folder.while the app launches in ipad the  low quality image is coming.(i think it is Default.png itself)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to give the images the right names, i.e. `Default-Landscape.png` etc. for iPad and add the supported orientations to your `Info.plist` file.

Please refer to http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1588.html

Answer (score 6):

You can use these files.

- Default~iphone.png
- Default@2x~iphone.png
- Default~ipad.png

[iOS Application Programming Guide - Build-Time Configuration Details](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BuildTimeConfiguration/BuildTimeConfiguration.html)

```
Providing Device-Specific Launch Images
~ipad. The launch image should be loaded on iPad devices only.
~iphone. The launch image should be loaded on iPhone or iPod touch devices only.
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep the iPad image name as "Default-Portrait.png" (768x1024)

And iPhone image name as "Default.png" (320x480).

Hope it will be helpful to you.

Let me know in case of any difficulty.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Found something that could be useful

In info.plist:

```
<key>UILaunchImageFile</key>
<string>Default</string>
<key>UILaunchImageFile~ipad</key>
<string>Default_iPad</string>
```

Then you need 2 files: Default.png (640x960 landscape) and Default_iPad.png (768x1024 landscape).

For details check this [link](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/5433)