# My image in UIView seems bigger than in Splash screen

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, splash-screen

I have designed an image with size 640x960, called Splash@2x.png.

I'm using this image in my App as splash image when the App is starting and it's also used in the first view of my App in a UIImage.
The UIImage size is 320x480 and same for the Parent UIView.

The issue is when the UIImage from my App replaces the Image from the Splash, it seems bigger and so it's not good user experience. Why it does not display exactly the same as in the Splash?

Help would be appreciated, thanks!

Séb.

Comment: Two things:  1)  is the filename Splash.png legal for a splash screen?  I always thought it was supposed to be some derivative of Default.png.  2)  There's some good information in this [closely related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634898/splash-screen-for-universal-application-for-ipad-and-iphone).

Answer (score 1):

are you telling it to load "Splash.png" or "Splash@2x.png"?  You should be specifying just "Splash.png"  the OS will call up @2x on its own if necessary.

Comment: In fact I have 2 version of the image, one with 320x480 (Default.png) and a second with 640x960 (Default@2x.png). For the Splash I don't need to provide any image name it gets (I suppose) by default the "Default@2x.png". For the UIImage in the IB, I set the field with "Default.png", it should select automatically the "Default@2x.png". I think my issue is really with UIImage because it's zoomed even in the IB.

Comment: Ah. Yeah if it looks wrong in IB then your problem is most likely there.  Check your dimensions and placement.

Comment: Sorry, the issue was not in IB, it was displayed ok in IB. I found the issue, I had to set the property "Wants Full Screen" on my ViewController. The image was shifted because of the tab bar. Now it's fixed ;-)