# xcode6.1 launchscreen launchimage blank

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode6, launch-screen

I know this question exists in numerous forums, but i did not quite find the right answer.
Well I'm working under xcode6.1 and developing a universal app, I added the launchimages to the image assets and in the target->general settings added the launchimage name required, then I launched the app and I got a white screen instead of the image.
Am I missing something?

Comment: If you are using a simulator then , delete the application from it. Quit the simulator. Try running again. Hope it helps!! if your images are configured correctly in all desired sizes and available in bundle. Cross verify it.

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634898/what-are-the-sizes-used-for-the-ios-application-splash-screen

Comment: No, I run on the device. But I tried to do that in the simulator too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Beneath the Launch Images Source is Launch Screen File option. By default it is set to LaunchScreen.xib You need to clear it. Then the xcode will pick Launch images from your image assests]

Beneath the Launch Images Source is Launch Screen File option. By default it is set to LaunchScreen.xib You need to clear it. Then the xcode6.1 will pick Launch images from your image assests

Comment: It works! Thanks, I should have thought about that in the first place :)